# Insert empty row in table to separate times each 30 minutes in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, time, html-table, separator

I'm showing certain information stored in a MySQL table in an HTML table. One of the columns of the table is of type "time". My idea is that the rows are spaced in groups of 30 minutes. The way it should be is as follows:

```
08:00
08:15
08:25
----separator
08:35
08:55
----separator
09:00
09:15
```

I managed to do something, but it does not work very well.

Here's what I've done:

```
<?$lastTime = '';?>
<?while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
<?$currentMinutes = substr($row["time"],3,2);?>
<?$lastMinutes = substr($lastTime,3,2);?>
<?if ( $lastTime <> '' and ($currentMinutes <> $lastMinutes) and ( ($lastMinutes <> '00' or $lastMinutes <> '30') and ($currentMinutes == '00' or $currentMinutes == '30' )  ) ){?>
<tr><td>Separator</td></tr>
<?}?>
<tr><td><?=$row["time"];?></td></tr>
<?$lastTime = $row["time"];?>
<?}?>
```

It is convenient to do this, or is there any way to solve it in the MySQL query?

Comment: You really don't need to close PHP on each line and re-open it on the next.  Makes the code difficult to read(not to mention the lack of whitespace/syntax nesting).

Comment: what is your actual query ? please try using group by for hours then we may split them

Comment: I know, sorry, I thought it would be easier to read. actually the code is an example. My table has many more fields. suppose my query is  "select time from mytable order by time"

Comment: I could do this in mysql only, but believe it done best in PHP, as otherwise it would not show mysql its propers playing to its strengths. Instead, turning it into a cheap report formatting engine, rather than a lean-and-mean data machine

Comment: should be using substr(4,2) and not 3,2

Comment: why ? the time format is hh:mm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could update your query to capture the intervals with

```
select `time`, subtime(`time`,maketime(0,mod(minute(`time`),30),0)) as period
from table;

time        period
08:00:00    08:00:00
08:15:00    08:00:00
08:25:00    08:00:00
08:35:00    08:30:00
08:55:00    08:30:00
09:00:00    09:00:00
09:15:00    09:00:00
```

You could have PHP code that outputs the separator whenever period changes from the previous value.

```
$period = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  if ($row['period'] != $period) {
    // Output separator
  }
  $period = $row['period'];
}
```

If you wanted to skip the first separator, then you could check that `$period != ''`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd probably just add a flag that I flip when I cross the half hour mark. Something like:

```
$previous_hour = null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $marker = 'first_thirty';
    $hour = substr($row["time"],0,2);
    $minutes = substr($row["time"],3,2);

    if ( $previous_hour && ( $previous_hour != $hour ) ) {
        $marker = 'first_thirty'
        //add searator
    } else {
        if ( $minutes >= 30 && $marker == 'first_thirty' ) {
            $marker = 'last_thirty'
            //add separator
        }
    }

    //do normal
    $previous_hour = $hour;
}
```

Comment: in this case you have the same problem as me, you're not considering the hours. if there is a hole between 09:00 and 10:00 the code would not notice the difference because the minutes did not change for example.

Comment: Good point - hadn't considered that scenario. I updated it to track the previous hour, which I think you'd need to in that case.